# 'RROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'database name

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu

I have a sh script with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -hmy.host.com --user=p387829 --password=pwd --
all-databases > /backup/mysqlall-`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d\%h\%i\%s`.sql

mysqldump -u p387829 -hmy.host.com --password=pwd --add-
drop-table --no-data usr_p387829_1 | grep ^DROP | mysql -up387829 -
pPwd -hmy.host.com usr_p387829_1

mysqldump -u p387829 -hmy.host.com --password=pwd 
usr_p387829_2 | mysql -u p387829 -pPwd -hmy.host.com 
usr_p387829_1
```

When I execute each command individually in my shell, it works. But when I execute *sh script.sh*

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
'RROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'usr_p387829_1
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
'RROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'usr_p387829_1
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but Google brought me here. Maybe it'll help someone.

bash (and probably other Linux shells as well) doesn't like CRLF, make sure to save the file with LF line breaks. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why that happened, I got the same error but I fix it by placing the password switch at the end of the line like so:

`mysql -r username 'database_name' -p'password'`

and it worked for me